# How to overwrite translations provided by google translate script?

Tags: javascript, google-translate

I'm using the translation script by google, and I was wondering if there is a way to overwrite the translation of specific words. The reason is that some words are translated like: "paket~~POS=HEADCOMP".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'no',
        includedLanguages: 'da,en,es,fr,sv',
        layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL,
        gaTrack: true,
        gaId: 'UA-1234567-8'
    }, 'google_translate_element');
}
```

This is the script i'm using. Couldn't find anything specific for this question (I would like a "google" way of doing it).
I have been told that it is possible without using https://cloud.google.com/translate/ , but I can't find anything relevant to this issue.

Comment: Maybe a simple if, else case on the string would make you create exceptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible.